# Function pass by reference

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

Recently a c++ expert told me that :

```
void f(int &*r);
```

is a valid pass by reference example although I thought this is some kind of pointer to a reference which is illegal. From my knowledge the correct form for pass by reference is either form of the following:

```
void f1(int *&r);
void f2(int &r);
```

Can you explain the situation of the first example (function f)?

Comment: Your "expert" was confused.

Comment: Im not sure but `int* &r` its a reference to a pointer, `int &r` int s reference to an int, never seen `int &*r`...

Comment: Did that person tell you that they were an expert, or did you assign the role to them yourself?

Comment: He is considered expert by the company he works for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one *(pointer to reference)* is **illegal** in all versions of C++.  The rest two are **legal**.

The bottomline : Ignore Your Instructor — he/she doesn't know C++, at least in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Its not allowed,

from C++ Standard 8.3.2/5:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and **no pointers to references**.

and also it does not compile, g++ outputs:

> error: cannot declare pointer to 'int&'